# Was Elizabeth Swaney the second lowest ranked competitor going into the women's halfpipe skiing?

Tags: olympics

Elizabeth Swaney got her own [twitter moment](https://twitter.com/TwitterMoments/status/965716393848180736) saying that she qualified for the women's halfpipe skiing by gaming the system. That she met the requirement of being in the top 30 by competing in events with fewer than 30 competitors, and then going to enough events to get sufficient points to qualify.

However, the Wikipedia article [Freestyle skiing at the 2018 Winter Olympics – Women's halfpipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freestyle_skiing_at_the_2018_Winter_Olympics_%E2%80%93_Women%27s_halfpipe) says that she had a bib number of 23, while Rosalind Groenewoud from Canada had a bib number of 24. The article [Freestyle skiing at the 2018 Winter Olympics – Qualification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freestyle_skiing_at_the_2018_Winter_Olympics_%E2%80%93_Qualification) mentions that four Canadians could have qualified but they only sent two, so I assume their competitors are reasonably strong.

The bib numbers and the results of competitors in the qualification seem fairly well correlated, so I assume they're based on a ranking. Groenewoud's [FIS profile](https://data.fis-ski.com/dynamic/athlete-biography.html?sector=FS&competitorid=121665&type=result) doesn't seem to indicate that she was out of action for a huge amount of time.

Was Swaney the lowest ranked competitor going into the women's halfpipe skiing? Also, if Swaney was the lowest ranked competitor, is there any individual we can point to as being denied a spot in women's halfpipe skiing as a result of her presence? There's the possibility that another Hungarian may have lost the ability to compete in another event, but that's a separate question.